# Powershell Script to sort files and put them into individual folders of different names

Tags: powershell

New to PowerShell so here goes... I have a bunch of xml files that have a sequential set of digits at the end as below.

HSUS_IMP_EN_NOM_I_00138001004.xml
HSUS_IMP_EN_NOM_I_00138002004.xml
HSUS_IMP_EN_NOM_I_00138003004.xml
HSUS_IMP_EN_NOM_I_00138004004.xml
.....

I would like to sort these files and place each one of them into its own folder like 1, 2, 3... So the above files would be put into there own folder based on sequence, example:

HSUS_IMP_EN_NOM_I_00138001004.xml goes to folder 1
HSUS_IMP_EN_NOM_I_00138002004.xml goes to folder 2 and so on.

I just cant seem to figure it out. My script just puts them into a folder of the same name which is incorrect.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\TEMP' 
$Files | ForEach-Object {

$FileFullName = $_.FullName
$foldername = $_.BaseName 
$destinationFolder = "C:\TEMP\$foldername\"
New-Item -Path C:\TEMP\$foldername -ItemType Directory
Move-Item $FileFullName $destinationFolder
}
```

Can anyone help with this dilemma

Comment: So you want the folder names to be exactly the same as the file without the extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the filenames are consistent then you can select a substring from the file name and use that to create the folder. In the example below, I've selected the 25th character in the filename but you can adjust this to whatever you need.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\TEMP' 
$Files | ForEach-Object {


$foldername = $_.Name.Substring(25,1)
$destinationFolder = "C:\TEMP\$foldername\"
New-Item -Path C:\TEMP\$foldername -ItemType Directory
Move-Item $_.FullName $destinationFolder
}
```

Edit: You will probably want to add the `-File` or `-filter *.xml` flag in the following line to avoid putting all your folders inside folders if you run the script twice.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\TEMP'
```